# Check If a Java array is a Palindrome from a certain element

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote a simple method to check if an array is a palindrome from a certain element. The problem is, I don't get any output from the method. There must be something wrong. Here is the code:

```java
public static boolean isPalindrome(int[] arr, int start) {
    if (arr.length == 0) { //empty array is a palindrome
        return true;
    }
    //loop from start to the end of array
    for (int i = start; i < arr.length; i++) {
        //loop from end of array to start
        for (int j = arr.length - 1; j >= start; j -= 1) {
            if (arr[i] != arr[j]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there's a bug.  You shouldn't have nested the two loops, because it means that you're comparing every entry `[i]` against every entry `[j]` and returning false as soon as there's a discrepancy.  You need just a single loop, in which both `i` and `j` are updated.

Comment: You are comparing one element picked from first loop with all elements picked in second. You can do it in just on loop by using index i and length-i.

Comment: As I write this comment, there are three answers here, and all of them are incorrect.  This is very sad.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this:

```java
for (int i = start; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    int first = arr[i];
    int second = arr[length - i - 1];

    if (first != second) return false;
}

return true;
```

This doesn't have two nested loops, but instead checks the same array, both from the front and the back.

Answer (score 0):

Single loop is enough to do this task, the thing is you just need to loop until half of the array that will be checked.

```java
public static boolean isPalindrome(int[] arr, int start)
{
    
    if (arr.length == 0) { //empty array is a palindrome
        return true;
    }

    //loop from start to the half of array
    for (int i = start; i < arr.length - arr.length / 2; i++) 
    {
        if (arr[i] != arr[arr.length - i - 1]) {
            return false;   
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this one.

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int[] arr, int start){
    
    if (arr.length == 0) { //empty array is a palindrome
        return true;
    }

    int end = arr.length - 1;

    while(start <= end){
      if(arr[start] != arr[end]){
        return false;
      }
      start++;
      end--;
    }

    return true;

}
```